# Will water leak into a base on a mosasaur platform

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

In Ark Survival Evolved, I finally managed to tame a mosasaur and build a platform with default settings and no cheats. I want to build a small home on the mosasaur's platform. Now let's say I put in a door and have no openings inside the little hut. If I take the mosasaur underwater, will water go through the hut or will it act as a sort of submarine?

Comment: in the basic ark game there is no water proof struktures. Wich means no your mosasaurus will not akt as a submarine

Comment: *This is not a constructive comment - sue me* - I really really wish that were possible, but I don't believe it is.  Excellent Idea!

Comment: There are plans to add a pump, of sorts, to allow water to be pumped from an area, or air to be pumped in, but there's been no timeline, that I've seen, on when they will implement it.  They have not mentioned it being able to be used, or not used, on platforms, however.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned in the comments and on [Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/346110/discussions/0/483367798510495941/), a Mosasaur base will flood underwater.

A developer made a statement in [Ark Digest #13](http://steamcommunity.com/app/346110/discussions/7/535152511378160963/) that suggests flood-proof base could be possible in the upcoming [Tek Tier](http://ark.gamepedia.com/Tek_Tier). Relevant quote below.

> Underwater bases, specifically, will use a new “Tek” tier of structures that are vacuum sealed. If the structure is completely enclosed, all doors are closed, and a unit per area called a “Venilator” is powered, then that volume will be free of water and you’ll have oxygen. If it’s not, you’ll be underwater and won’t have oxygen. You can construct air locks to provide a method of entering and exiting that doesn’t flood the inner compartments.